# SwiftUI Updating EnvironmentObject outside the view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a model called `UserData` which is used only for the current logged in user. It saves data as profile data, user id, reference to Firestore document, etc.

I'm injecting this as an `@EnvironmentObject` so I can have access to it everywhere.

```
final class UserData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var profile = Profile.default
    @Published var loggedIn: Bool = Auth.auth().currentUser != nil ? true : false
    @Published var uid: String = ""
    @Published var documentReference: DocumentReference = Firestore.firestore().document("")
}
```

I also have a UserViewModel with methods on it.

```
class UserViewModel: ObservableObject {
    func login(email: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (Response) -> Void) {
        AuthService().login(email: email, password: password) { (response: Response) in
            // let error = response.error

            completion(response)
        }
    }

    func register(email: String, password: String, firstName: String, lastName: String, completion: @escaping (Response) -> Void) {
        AuthService().register(email: email, password: password, firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName) { (response: Response) in
            // let error = response.error

            completion(response)
        }
    }

    func logout() {
        try? Auth.auth().signOut()
    }
}
```

The issue arrives in the View

```
@EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData
var userViewModel = UserViewModel()

func login() {
    if self.email == "" || self.password == "" {
        self.error = "You must provide both an email and password"
    } else {
        self.userViewModel.login(email: self.email, password: self.password) { response in
            self.userData.profile = response.profile!
            self.userData.uid = response.uid
            self.userData.documentReference = response.documentReference ?? Firestore.firestore().document("")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(response.userDefaults, forKey: "userDefaults")
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I can not update this UserModel so easily. I have to update each of its properties one by one and also for the registration I have to do the same thing. Same thing in the SceneDelegate. I have the same lines in three different places, login view, registration view, and SceneDelegate

```
self.userData.profile = response.profile!
self.userData.uid = response.uid
self.userData.documentReference = response.documentReference ?? Firestore.firestore().document("")
UserDefaults.standard.set(response.userDefaults, forKey: "userDefaults")
```

Is there a better way to handle such things? Like having a single place to update this `@EnvironmentObject`. They are really cool to use them in the view but updating them outside the view is a real pain. Also It doesn't work well with the UserViewModel since I can not pass `UserData` to the `UserViewModel`.

How can I properly use this `@EnvironmentObject` called UserData